# How can I run ncurses program with 256 colors in the gnome terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, ncurses

My problem:

I want to run ncurses in 256-colors mode in the gnome terminal.

I already know that you can turn on this color mode with:

```
# export TERM=xterm-256color
```

But this solution is not permanent. When ever a new Gnome terminal is opened, it returns to 8 color support again.

So how can I export TERM, such that this solution above becomes permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the command you wish to be applied to every terminal to your `.bashrc` file, in your home directory:

```
echo 'if [[ $TERM == @(xterm|screen) ]]; then
    export TERM=$TERM-256color;
fi' >> ~/.bashrc
```

And it will be run every time you open a new shell.

Comment: Edited to check the old `$TERM` value; it is outright wrong to force `xterm-256color` if the old value is something like `screen` or `linux`.